# How to send the files in a directory to the printer in Perl?

Tags: perl, shell, printing, lpr

Okay, here's what I'm trying to do:

I have an email with a series of MIME attachments. I have sample code that will get me as far as creating a directory with the decoded attachments in it; what I need to do now is send the contents of that directory to lpr. (I'm not screening out bad file formats; I'm leaving it up to the spooler daemon to deal with.)

Answer (score 7):

What about using [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @files = glob($decode_directory/*);
system "lpr", @files;
```

You can make the `glob` argument more selective.  The [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function written thus avoids launching a shell and runs the `lpr` command directly.